# docker-compose replays past output on container reboot

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

It appears that docker-compose replays captured output on container re-launch.  This is against expectation, and is misleading about what my container is actually doing.  Can this be disabled?

For instance,

- I have a simple service that logs and exits w/ code 0.
- In docker-compose.yml, i have `restart: always` set.

When running `docker-compose up`, each time the logging container comes back up after existing, I see all previous output relogged, plus any new additions from the current run.

[Here's an easy to run example](https://github.com/cdaringe/docker-distributed-logging/tree/26b422ac327f7d64c0257d5199d88f12f20c5121/fluentd).

- clone, `cd <project>/fluentd`, `docker-compose build`, & `docker-compose up`

I'm using docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac21 on OSX.

Tips would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an [open issue with Docker](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1946), where it's replaying logs on `up`. A workaround [is mentioned  here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1946#issuecomment-137911871):

> alias docker-logs-truncate="docker-machine ssh default -- 'sudo find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -iname \"*json.log\"|xargs -I{} sudo dd if=/dev/null of={}'"

Answer (score 0):

Is this a life cycle problem? There is a difference between a stop and a "rm". If you do a docker-compose stop, the containers are suspended. Use "docker-compose up" to restart them from last time.
But "docker-compose rm" will destroy the containers. docker-compose up again to recreate them from scratch.

Comment: hello, thx for the input.  im not sure this is relevant to the question.  my use case is `compose up` and walk away.  when i return, my console is full of redundant logs from a container that is (expectedly) cycling.  that is, if container A logs "random-number-1" and exits, on second container start from an "up" compose state, my stdout now contains "random-number-1" "random-number-1" (again) and "random-number-2".

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Did you try to remove the restart always for your container?

Comment: indeed.  in fact, if i ctrl-c and it stops all running compose services, on next up, it replays all the stdout yet again, quickly.

Comment: Did you mount your logs in a volume? That could explain why you see old logs.

Comment: nah--there are no log files--just stdout.  I suppose docker secretly keeps the logs on my behalf somewhere on my system, but as demonstrated in the "easy-to-run" example above, no such configuration is used.